# PHP Counter to Count how many enteries were entered

Tags: php, html, duplicates, counter

If any one can help me in php  I will be really thankful.I am a new to php and I am working on a project and in that my part is to get input using a text box and save it into a text file with timestamp.
I am able to do this and my code is working correctly .
 but  i am unable to do few requirements like having a counter how many entries were entered and if the entry is a duplicate don't add to the file. I try to include a counter it always show me 1  as the file reload every time . I want a textbox again to get more entries thats y i am reloading it again.

```
<h1>please scan your student id card :)</h1>
<form action = "barcodeHandler.php" method = "POST">

<input type = "text" name = "barcode" style= "width:400PX; height:40PX;opacity:10" autofocus>
<input type = "submit" style= "width:0px; height:0px;opacity:0;" value = "barcodeSubmit" >

</form>

<?php
   $counter = 0;
//$filePath = getenv("HOMEDRIVE").getenv("HOMEPATH")."\Desktop";     // use this when using windows will give user desktop dir
//$filePath = "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PHP_Lessons/project"; // setting file directory
$filePath = "./";

$course = "MCI";
$extensionOfFile = ".txt";
$dateForFile = date ("d_m_Y");

$fileName = "/$course"."_"."$dateForFile"."$extensionOfFile ";             // name of the file 

if(!empty($_POST['barcode']))
{
    $barcode = $_POST['barcode'];        // getting barcode
    $time = time();                      // unix time stamp
    $actual_time = date('H:i:s',$time);   // actual time
    $file = $filePath.$fileName;
    $entry = $barcode .", ".date ("d-m-Y"). " ".$actual_time;  // putting in the data in variable
    $handle = fopen("$file",'a');          // open a file
    fwrite($handle,$entry."\r\n");       // "/r/n" will give a line break
    fclose($handle);                 // free the file
    //echo date_default_timezone_get();    // if required to check the timezone of the server

     $counter++;

}
echo $counter;
header("location :barcodeHandler.php");    // redirect to the form
?>
```

Comment: What are you counting?

Comment: I'd suggest using file names of the format year month day, and prepend log lines with `date('c', $timestamp)`.  It will make sorting and finding files and entries easier.

Comment: in my code say value entered in the textbox is "barcode10" which i am saving in the variable $barcode.then writting it into a txt file . then again value enterd in textbox is "barcode10" which is already scanned before and  is written in the file but i want  if barcode is already in the file  i will not write it in the text file i just throw it away.

Comment: A simple pre-check (to not add entries if already in log file) is to see if your log file contains a barcode string.  See:  Php's file_get_contents and strpos functions.

Comment: Thanks alot mate i got an idea now working on my code Thank you heaps

Answer (score 2):

Your counter will only return 1 as it isn't counting the entries already present in the file.

```
<h1>please scan your student id card :)</h1>
<form action = "barcodeHandler.php" method = "POST">

<input type = "text" name = "barcode" style= "width:400PX; height:40PX;opacity:10" autofocus>
<input type = "submit" style= "width:0px; height:0px;opacity:0;" value = "barcodeSubmit" >

</form>

<?php
   $counter = 0;
//$filePath = getenv("HOMEDRIVE").getenv("HOMEPATH")."\Desktop";     // use this when using windows will give user desktop dir
//$filePath = "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PHP_Lessons/project"; // setting file directory
$filePath = "./";

$course = "MCI";
$extensionOfFile = ".txt";
$dateForFile = date ("d_m_Y");

$fileName = "/$course"."_"."$dateForFile"."$extensionOfFile ";             // name of the file 

if(!empty($_POST['barcode']))
{
    $barcode = $_POST['barcode'];        // getting barcode
    $time = time();                      // unix time stamp
    $actual_time = date('H:i:s',$time);   // actual time
    $file = $filePath.$fileName;
    $entry = $barcode .", ".date ("d-m-Y"). " ".$actual_time;  // putting in the data in variable
    $handle = fopen("$file",'a');          // open a file
    fwrite($handle,$entry."\r\n");       // "/r/n" will give a line break
    fclose($handle);                 // free the file
    //echo date_default_timezone_get();    // if required to check the timezone of the server
    $countExisting = count(explode("\r\n", file_get_contents($file))) - 1; // minus 1 as every row has \r\n appended

     $counter = $countExisting;

}
echo $counter;
header("location :barcodeHandler.php");    // redirect to the form
?>
```

This should do what you want it to.

Comment: Thanks alot mate  Thanks for your help. it is working correctly i tried to count the strings in the file before but it was showing me  +1 all the time (actually lines 4  count shows 5 ) i was not able to figure out why it is like that  .  if you have any clarification please clear my confusion.

Comment: and bro if you can give some sugestion how can i handle the dulplicate . in my code if $barcode is alredy being scanned is their anyway i not write it in the file .